# Custom View in Advanced Search not showing information

Tags: profile, advanced-search

I'm having an odd situation where a custom view that I created for Advanced Search sometimes shows information and other times does not show information within the same search.  Has anyone had this happen before?  I can confirm that the first record in this picture does have information stored in the current citizenship field.  We are using 5.16.4.

[image]

Comment: is that field a multi-record field?

Comment: Yes, it is a multi-record field.  This first line only has one record in the field, just like the second line that says 'Zimbabwean'.